# Good Translations of the Organon

Tags: logic, history-of-philosophy, aristotle, greeks, translation

I can't seem to find a translation of Aristotle's famous Organon that is consistently given good reviews. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Check Wikipedia, Organon > References > Primary Sources, for translations of the individual works that became the Organon.

Comment: Robin Smith's edition of Aristotle's *Prior Analytics* (Hackett, 1989)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for all texts that compose the Organon from a single translator you may consider that of Thomas Taylor or Octavius Freire Owen.

Coincidentally, I've been looking into this myself within these last few days and that is what I have found.